# Scala None instance not == None

Tags: scala

I've got an intermittent problem in Scala code where I'm working with values from an immutable map with String keys. Here's the basic code, including debug logging I added:

```
  val compStruct = subsq.comps get (ident)
  compStruct match {
    ...
    case None =>
      logger.info(s"Found None, of type ${compStruct.getClass.getName}, at position $position (ident $ident)")
      ...
    case x =>
      logger.info(s"Illegal structure of type ${x.getClass.getName} at position $position (ident $ident) - x == None is ${x == None}, x.getClass == None.getClass is ${x.getClass == None.getClass}, x.getClass.getName == None.getClass.getName (${None.getClass.getName}) is ${x.getClass.getName == None.getClass.getName}")
      ...
  }
```

the problem is that case x is sometimes taken when the value is actually a None, as shown by the (sanitized) debug output:

```
  INFO  ...: Found None, of type scala.None$, at position 3000 (ident XX)
  INFO  ...: Illegal structure of type scala.None$ at position 3200 (ident XX) - x == None is false, x.getClass == None.getClass is true, x.getClass.getName == None.getClass.getName (scala.None$) is true
```

(The first line is what I'd expect to happen and indeed does happen normally; the rest are the error case)

So if my logging is to be believed (and I haven't messed up my expression somehow) I've got a case where the map is returning x, where x is an instance of class scala.None$ (the *same* class scala.None$ as seen by the compiled code) but doesn't match the case None and x == None is false.

A classloading issue would be the obvious cause, but x.class == None.class seems to preclude that.

Added: As I suggested in the comments, I can reproduce the instances of None not matching with the following code:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val none1 = None
    val clas = this.getClass.getClassLoader.loadClass("scala.None$")
    val constr = clas.getDeclaredConstructors()(0)
    constr.setAccessible(true)
    val none2 = constr.newInstance()
    println(s"none1 == none2 is ${none1 == none2}")
    println(s"none1 == None is ${none1 == None}")
    println(s"none2 == None is ${none2 == None}")
  }
}
```

Which gives:

```
none1 == none2 is false
none1 == None is false
none2 == None is true
```

I don't think that has anything to do with what's happening in the application, though.

Added: I modified the actual None$ classfile to both print a message when the constructor executes and throw an exception if the None$.MODULE$ value is non-null when the constructor is called, and even moved the store to the static MODULE$ value to the static constructor block (the original code had this store in the constructor, which I think is technically a violation of JVM rules since the object is not considered initialized until after the constructor returns).

This does block the reflection call to the constructor (above code sample) that duplicated the symptoms of the problem, but doesn't change anything in the actual application. The value of None$.MODULE$ changes from one execution of the code to the next, even though the class remains the same (same System.identityHashCode), yet the constructor is only called once.

Comment: Maybe show the type declaration of subsq.comps. Also are you serializing anything into play here from another virtual machine or loading the entire subsq in some way (network/disk?) .. also try showing the hash key of your debugged objects and compare like this: scala.None.hashCode , x.hashCode perhaps they don't match?

Comment: The types aren't really relevant here in any way I can see, only the None. None$ is a singleton class in Scala, with a private constructor only called from a static initialization block, The constructor that sets the value of the.MODULE$ static final to the instance of the class (I'm not sure why this is done in the constructor - interesting approach).

Comment: None$ does not redefine equals() or hashCode(), so it's using the base Object implementations. So if you can somehow get a second instance of None$ it would not be == None. That matches my results, but doesn't explain how another instance of None$ could be created.

None$ does provide the readResolve() method, returning the static MODULE$ value, so deserialization should not create a different instance.

Comment: I agree I looked at None's source and concluded the same.  That's about the end of the line for my expertise on "why" but I can suggest that this fix might work.. test  case Some(x) => //code followed with a case _ => //catch all aka None case. Should work since the extractor code for Some(x) will test the type a lot cleaner.

Comment: Actually, somebody using reflection to call the private constructor method could potentially explain the situation - that would change the standard None$ to a new one. But in this case the weird None is being returned by Map.get, and that's happening "immediately" after the expected None is returned by Map.get from a separate map. So still puzzling.

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense as a workaround, but without understanding the problem I'm reluctant to start trying to code around it.

Comment: yeah I can see your point on that

Comment: You can try also to check `System.identityHashCode` to identify if that is another instance

Comment: It seems creating different Node object using Reflection does not make sense as your description, but the new None object is truely re-created by your code, and it's hard to reproduce the problem with the excerpt code. Can u provide more information about the code which generate the problem, like the type of Map, execution scenario.

Comment: Creating a second None using reflection was just an attempt to recreate the issue. It matched the observed conditions, but is not the cause of the problem (a class file with the constructor patched to throw an exception on reuse caused the reflection code to fail, while the original problem still occurred). This happens in an enterprise environment which cannot easily be recreated, but the Map which works (returns new None) on the second pass is an immutable.Map$Map4, the one that fails (returns old None) is an immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap. Both are constructed on the first pass and reused.

Comment: Maybe you should open a bug in Scala bugtracker. They might give you some additional ways to troubleshoot.

Comment: Can you show how are you populating your Map, or at least an abstraction of the algorithm? The new instance of None could be created at that point. I don't think anyone could help you with this problem with the given information, as None is defined as a case object, so there is no straight forward method to inject a new instance to you Map. 
If it is populated via reflection (json/xml serialization, or something), a bad configuration of the serializer could be causing this behavior.

Comment: Try adding the none2 match { .... in your test object and you will see that reflection does not explain what happened. It will not match either None or x.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your test:
`None` is an object in Scala. When you define
`val none1 = None`, you assign to `none1` this object, which is supposed to be a singleton.

By using reflection, you are bypassing the private constructor and creating a new instance of None class. The `==` operator will only return `true` if the two pointers are pointing to the same object. 
You can verify the memory address of these objects by using `System.identityHashCode(none1)` and compare it.

Also, if you try to run your match against none1 in your object Test, you will run into a match error, as the second instance of None does not match either None or x.

I was able to reproduce your error. By running this code:

```
val a = Map("a" -> "b", "b" -> None)
a.get("b") match { 
   case None => print("None")
   case x => print("X") 
}  // Prints X
a.get("c") match { 
    case None => print("None")
    case x => print("X") 
} // Prints None
```

I know that this does not explains why it prints X, but at least you know when...

Because your HashMap has None values, it is a HashMap[String,java.io.Serializable] rather than HashMap[String,String].
And the call to get will return a java.io.Serializable rather than a String.

To solve your problem and get it to match when it is None, you can do:

```
case x if(x.isInstanceOf[None$]) =>
```

Comment: That means adding a type annotation of `HashMap[String, String]` to `a` or `compStruct` of the OP should make the compiler point out the problem, right? I suppose that choosing `java.io.Serializable` as common type for the values of the Map was not intended by the programmer.

Comment: Exactly @SvenKoschnicke!

Answer (score 0):

Take note that the way a `None` is processed in your context of code is via an `Option[A]` where by not specifying the case for your second condition, it means that you are allowing `None` to be a part of the second case.

What you should do is process the `map.get` into this way if you are trying to achieve on getting the case which is not a `None`

```
val compStruct = subsqs.comp.get(ident)
compStruct match {
  case None => ...
  case x: Some(_) => ...
}
```